# how to manage current database to the next year of school management

Tags: database-design

i am developing school management system

i have student record form and database table student record.

i just fill information and stored in database.

but next year student goes to next class that is next standard. then how i can manage this student information for previous year. i want to manage then should i registered again this student next year or any other idea that next year i will manage that particular student record. because i want to registered student once and manage its record for every year.

so please tel me the idea or database design or any logic...

please help me.

Comment: As a teacher myself, I can relate...
Students enroll, so keep a seperate record of enrollments and students. (Apart from student records.) Whenever a school year ends, all current enrollments are ended automatically and students advance a year (if the same field of study is available). A new enrollment is created. We can view a list of previous enrollments at any given time.

Comment: I would also advise you to take a look at [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/freshness:recently-updated/?q=school%20management)... There are a number of good solutions already there.

Comment: thanks for answer. but how automatically enrollment end and new one is created. i dont understand it. please explain

Comment: Either manually, by executing code on the click of a button, or fully automated using cronjobs. Two tables: students / enrollments --> add start & end date from enrollment, together with studentID you get from students-table (you can even use this within the same school year, to allow for changes in field of study).
Update last record in enrollment table for student --> change the end date to current date.
Write a new record to enrollment table using the current date as start date.

Comment: What do "image", "fonts" and "title" have to do with this question?

Comment: font image nothing with this Q but stack overflow want to put this tags to check either this is developer or not